# How to debug random DYGLInitPlatform connection to host has failed errors on app launch?

Tags: ios, lldb

Randomly and seemingly without any noticeable pattern, I get the following error at app launch that never gets past the launch screen:

```
2020-09-11 11:38:36.809281-0700 Pineapple[5448:1115742] [DYGLInitPlatform] connection to host has failed: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"
2020-09-11 11:38:36.811548-0700 Pineapple[5448:1115742] aborting: platform initialization failed
```

Thread list:

```
(lldb) thread list
Process 5448 stopped
  thread #1: tid = 0x1105df, 0x000000019e76377c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__ulock_wait + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread'
* thread #2: tid = 0x11065e, 0x000000019e762d88 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  thread #3: tid = 0x11065f, 0x000000019e763940 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
```

Thread backtrace:

```
(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #2, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x000000019e762d88 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x000000019e67b1e8 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 136
    frame #2: 0x000000019e5ce934 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 100
    frame #3: 0x0000000108919d70 GPUToolsCore`dy_abort + 176
    frame #4: 0x00000001088eaa74 GPUToolsCore`GPUTools::Interpose::DYInterposeCommonInit(DYGuestAppClient* (*)(), int) + 428
    frame #5: 0x00000001088fb108 GPUToolsCore`GPUTools::Interpose::DYInterposeThreadEntry(void*) + 40
    frame #6: 0x000000019e683d98 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 156
```

How can I track this down? Some have suggested cleaning the build folder but that does not remedy the situation.

Comment: Having the same issue. I'll try to post here if I can find anything. Any luck with this so far ?